# WP / PHP function to extract the image doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I use often this function to extract the image of a post:

```
function first_post_image($content) {
$first_img = '';
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
return $first_img;
}
```

then I show the image with the following code

```
<?php $postimage = first_post_image(get_the_content()); ?> // catch the image
<img src="<?php echo $postimage; ?>" /> //view the image
```

Now I tryed to use this function in my last template (wp), but the image doesn't appear. I can see the tag img and the src attribute, but it is empty.

Someone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a `var_dump( $postimage );` to see what the function is returning?

Here is one that works and instead of returning an empty array if there are no images it will return false so you can specify a backup or default image.

```
    /**
     * Extracts the first image in the post content
     *
     * @param object $post the post object
     * @return bool|string false if no images or img src
     */
    function extract_image( $post ) {
        $html = $post->post_content;
        if ( stripos( $html, '<img' ) !== false ) {
            $regex = '#<\s*img [^\>]*src\s*=\s*(["\'])(.*?)\1#im';
            preg_match( $regex, $html, $matches );
            unset( $regex );
            unset( $html );
            if ( is_array( $matches ) && ! empty( $matches ) ) {
                return  $matches[2];

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some test and finally I solve the problem. I don't know if I make a mistake, but the code is the same and now work correctly.
Thanks.